# After Uninstall, Android Device Manager still shows in Device Administrator List

Tags: android-device-manager, device-administrator

I enabled Android Device Manager a while ago, and then realized it wasn't useful for me so uninstalled it.

I just now noticed that it still is listed in my Device Administrators list despite not being installed on my phone (and if I log in to their website I can STILL track my phone)

Am running Android 4.2.2 on an HTC One X (unrooted)

Answer (score 6):

The Android Device Manager app doesn't control whether your device is tracked by ADM. It simply allows you to see and manage your other Android devices.

You need to go to the Google Settings app, choose "Android Device Manager", and un-check "Remotely locate this device".